# how to use memcpy with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, memcpy

I was trying to learn smart pointer as i came across this.

```
{ //Example 1
    //String to be copied
    std::string strHello = "HelloWorld1";
    int size = strHello.length();

    //Creating Ptr using make_unique
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pstrText;
    pstrText = make_unique<char[]>(size + 1); // Allocating +1 for \0

    //Copying values to the new pointer
    int r = memcpy_s(pstrText.get(), size + 1, strHello.c_str(), size);

    //Printing
    std::cout << pstrText.get() << std::endl;
}

{ //Example 2
    //String to be copied
    std::string strHello = "HelloWorld2";
    int size = strHello.length();

    //Creating Ptr using make_unique
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pstrText;
    pstrText = make_unique<char[]>(size);

    //Copying values to the new pointer
    int r = memcpy_s(pstrText.get(), size, strHello.c_str(), size);

    //Printing
    std::cout << pstrText.get() << std::endl;
}
{//Example 3

    //String to be copied
    std::string strHello = "HelloWorld3";
    int size = strHello.length();

    //Creating Ptr using make_unique
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pstrText;
    pstrText = make_unique<char[]>(size + 1); //Allocating + 1

    //Copying values to the new pointer
    int r = memcpy_s(pstrText.get(), size, strHello.c_str(), size);

    //Printing
    std::cout << pstrText.get() << std::endl;
}

{//Example 4

    //String to be copied
    std::string strHello = "HelloWorld4";
    int size = strHello.length();

    //Creating Ptr using make_unique
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pstrText;
    pstrText = make_unique<char[]>(size);

    //Copying values to the new pointer
    int r = memcpy_s(pstrText.get(), size + 1, strHello.c_str(), size); 

    //Printing
    std::cout << pstrText.get() << std::endl;
}
```

The Output is as Follows using VS 2013 Debug(Win32):

> ```
> HelloWorld1
> HelloWorld2²²²²½½½½½½½½■
> HelloWorld3
> HelloWorld4²²²²½½½½½½½½■
> ```

1. If Example 1 is correct why does the Example 3 also give the correct output?
2. What Does the garbage values at the end signify?
3. Why didn't the compiler throw any error or exception?
4. In Example 4 Why is there no error when we had tried to copy a value at the end but was not initialized
5. How do we properly initialize a smart pointer in this case? Will anything change if it a BYTE array instead of char;

Comment: I recommend using `std::copy` rather than `memcpy` and variants. It is as fast and is safer.

Comment: @Galik for the specific case of copying `char`s, it isn't any safer

Comment: @Caleth Avoiding `memcpy` altogether makes coding safer. If you use `memcpy` in the wrong place it is a problem. You can avoid that possibility by simply not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If Example 1 is correct why does the Example 3 also give the correct output?

`make_unique<char[]>(size + 1);` initialises all the `char`s to 0. Both example 1 and 3 don't overwrite this, because they copy respectively the smaller of `size + 1` and `size`; and the smaller of `size` and `size`. I.e. they both copy `size` `char`s

> What Does the garbage values at the end signify?

That your program has undefined behaviour. `std::ostream::operator<<(char *)` *in this case* reads bytes until it sees a 0.

> Why didn't the compiler throw any error or exception?

Because C++ is not safe. Rather than defining a particular behaviour (such as throwing an exception) when you access outside an array, the *whole program* isn't bound by the rules of C++. This is called "Undefined Behaviour".

> In Example 4 Why is there no error when we had tried to copy a value at the end but was not initialized

Because C++ is not safe

> How do we properly initialize a smart pointer in this case? Will anything change if it a BYTE array instead of char;

Either example 1 or example 3 is fine. However, why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: I have a problem with "C++ is not safe" part - is a Train unsafe because somebody died on the tracks? Is a car unsafe because somebody crashed taking a corner too fast? Or is alcohol unsafe, because somebody lost consciousness from drinking too much? In C++ the safe construct is to use a `vector` (or `array`) with `at` accessor.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk it's a statement of fact. "Certain other operations are described in this document as undefined (for example, the effect of attempting to modify a const object). [ Note: This document imposes no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined behavior. — end note ]"

Comment: It's not a fact - it's an opinion.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk and yes, those things *are* unsafe. I'm not saying that C++ is *bad*. A more apt comparison is saying that a table-saw is unsafe, you can cut limbs off if you don't use it correctly

Comment: "_Because C++ is not safe_", "_if you don't use it correctly_" ?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk In a safer language, "not using it correctly" would have a defined result at runtime. In a safe language, "not using it correctly" would be a build-time error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207189/discussion-between-caleth-and-robert-andrzejuk).

Comment: "Example 1 copies the string's terminating 0, Example 3 keeps the one from the initialisation" Neither of these examples copies the terminating byte. Both of these examples specify `size` as their last parameter instead of `size + 1` and thus only copy up to the length of the string. Example 1 and 3, in the end, perform the exact same set of operations.

Answer (score 4):

Two things you need to know:

First is that in C++ [`memcpy_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcpy-s-wmemcpy-s?view=vs-2019) is a Microsoft VC++ CRT specific extension. It exists in C (added in the C11 standard), but even then the Microsoft implementations of the safe functions are often not following the C standard.

The second thing, and which is the cause of your problem, is that the last argument is the number of bytes to copy. Since you only specify `size` there, your call will not copy the string null-terminator. You need to copy `size + 1` bytes:

```
int r = memcpy_s(pstrText.get(), size + 1, strHello.c_str(), size + 1);
//                                                               ^^^^
//                    Copy plus one, to also copy the null-terminator
```

Comment: `memcpy_s` is NOT Microsoft specific: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy. Is available since C11.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Well, to be honest almost all the "safe" functions originates from Microsoft extensions, and their implementation is usually not following the C standard.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk "available since C11" but not in C++ with compilers other than msvc afaik

Comment: @idclev463035818 Agreed, it is optional: _Only if the implementation defines__STDC_LIB_EXT1__and additionally the user code defines__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__before any inclusion of<string.h>_